# UnsupportedClassVersionError in Hadoop despite the version being correct

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, javac

When I am running a JAR file using Hadoop, I am running into this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: WordCount has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:405)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
```

It used to work before but I don't know why it suddenly stopped working. I think after trying this I had worked on some other code and now when I went back to this it started giving this error.

I have tried:

1. Both multi-node and single-node.
2. I used update-alternatives to set java, javac and jar to the openJDK 8 version.
3. I have tried target -8 in the javac command.
4. I tried 2 ways to compile it:
   `bin/hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java`
   and
   `javac WordCount.java -cp $HADOOP_CLASSPATH`
5. Also tried compiling and jar using the entire path like /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac and the same path/jar.
6. I have tried getting the JAR file from someone else for whom the command is working. Using the same JAR file also gave the same error.

I am really at a loss. How do I proceed now?

I have Java 11 and 8 installed but I have checked JAVA_HOME, javac -version and java -version. They are correct. hadoop-env.sh is also set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop does not support Java 11 until latest version 3.3.4

If you have both 8 and 11 installed and are not using that version, I'd suggest uninstalling Java 11 completely from your systems.

Same goes for **external** systems that run that JAR file, such as YARN ResourceManagers.

I'd recommend using Maven/Gradle to compile JARs, not manually running `javac`